# How can I create a monthly total using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with large number of variables. A subset:

```
ID month val   tt 
a  Jan   3    0.76
a  Jan   4    0.65
a  Feb   5    0.67
b  Mar   23   0.25
b  Apr   3    0.25
c  Jan   5    0.22
d  Aug   5    0.44
c  Sep   7    0.21
e  Oct   3    0.77
```

I want to find how many times each month occurred in each ID.

Expected solution (Illustration, doesn't tally with given dataframe):

```
ID  Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun etc.
a   20  25  51
b   4   65  54
c   14  11  44
d   78  44  41
```

Currently, I am doing it in a very crude way by using the table command after subsetting the data for each ID. And would like to do it using dplyr.

```
df %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(count=n())
```

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Though I would like to become more familiar with dplyr library, your solution is giving me this: ID month 
    1     1

Comment: ID is character. Not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: I think I got the answer using the count function.

Comment: I find it strange that someone is commenting and then deleting their comments. :/ Unless something is wrong at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option for you. I treated `month` as character. I created a master data frame which contains 12 months for each ID. Then, I used `count()`. In this way, you do not have to use `group_by()` and `summarize()`. Merge the master data frame with the other data frame. I used `spread()` to convert the outcome to a wide format. Finally, I reordered months in `select()` using `match()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

master <- expand.grid(ID = unique(mydf$ID), month = month.abb, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

count(mydf, ID, month) %>%
full_join(master) %>% # or right_join(master) %>%
spread(key = month, value = n, fill = 0) %>%
select(ID, match(month.abb, names(temp)))

#     ID   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
#  (chr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
#1     a     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#2     b     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#3     c     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
#4     d     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
#5     e     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "c", 
"e"), month = c("Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Jan", "Aug", 
"Sep", "Oct"), val = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 23L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L), 
tt = c(0.76, 0.65, 0.67, 0.25, 0.25, 0.22, 0.44, 0.21, 0.77
)), .Names = c("ID", "month", "val", "tt"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```